# Iteration function in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have a function like this

```
iter :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a    
iter n f a = f (f ... (f a) .. )
```

how can i define such function in un-typed lambda calculus ?

any hint/help will be appreciated.

Comment: you might get a better response at: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dhaivat: Sure, if you count "This question is for research-level questions only - please read the FAQ" as a better response.

Comment: Its not really research level, but, I doubt that one could find many people who work with lambda calculus on SO, seeing that it is a highly "work-based" community.

Comment: The question is bogus: what does `...` mean?  (I know what you think it means, but that's exactly where your problem is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers do not exist *per se* in pure lambda calculus. You have to design a representation for numbers (and show that indeed those behave like numbers). The basic idea is that you can define numbers so that they are *exactly* the iteration function you need : `n` would be a lambda term that, when given a function `f`, compute the `n`th iteration of `f`.

This is an idea known as [Church Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are absolutely right, i figured it out later, it would give the Church numerals representation in lambda calculus

Answer (score 0):

```
iter == (rec g (fn f (fn n (fn x ((= n 0) x (g f (- n 1) (f x)))))))
```

Comment: I designed and implemented a lisp dialect that is strongly typed with implicit types where the iter function could be written as follows using y-comb: `(let ((p (fn u (fn v (v ((u u) v)))))
 (Y (p p))
 (iter (Y (fn (lazy iter)
      (fn (n f a)
   ((eqw n 0)
    a
    (iter (subw n 1) f (f a))))))))
    (iter 3 (fn x (mulw x x)) 2))` and also as: `((label iter
  (fn (n f a)
      ((eqw n 0)
       a
       (iter (subw n 1) f (f a)))))
    3 (fn x (mulw x x)) 2)`

Comment: using the iter function we can construct a cyclic structure as follows: `((label iter
  (fn (n f a)
      ((eqw n 0)
       a
       (iter (subw n 1) f (f a)))))
    3 (fn x (set (cdr x) (cons x nil))) (cons nil nil))`